# LINQ sum of one column and insert to another table C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, linq

i have two tables suck as the one below i wanna know how to sum "calorie" column based on name from table 1 and then insert the value to table 2

```
table1(PK->ID(int),Name(nvarchar),amount(int),calorie(int))
table2(pk->ID(int),name(nvarchar),totalcalorie(int))

+-------+--------+----------+--------------+
| int   |  name  | amount   |    calorie   |
+-------+--------+----------+--------------+
|     1 |    a   |       10 |     20       |
|     2 |    b   |        5 |     20       |
|     2 |    b   |       10 |     10       |
|     1 |    a   |       10 |     10       |
|     2 |    b   |       15 |     35       |
|     3 |    c   |       20 |     15       |
+-------+--------+----------+--------------+
```

something like this is my first table now imagine same kinda table for table2
only this time  something like :

```
1-------a--------30
2-------b--------65
3-------c--------15
```

is this possible at all? what i wrote till now and doesn't work is this :

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var q = from row in db.table1
                group row by new { row.name }
                    into grp
                    select new
                    {
                        grp.Key.name,
                        sum = grp.Sum(row => row.calorie)
                    };
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: You just want sum of calorie group by username?

Comment: sorry im kinda new to the site.ok so using grid view doesn't solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Now you are just selecting data. You need the block for insertion like the following:

```
var q = (from row in db.table1
        group row by new { row.id, row.name } into grp
        select new
        {
            grp.Key.id,
            grp.Key.name,
            sum = grp.Sum(s => s.calorie)
        }).ToList();

foreach(var item in q)
{
    var e = new db.table2Entity
    {
        id = item.id,
        name = item.name,
        totalcalorie = item.sum
    };
    db.Table2.AddObject(e);      
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not see the result on you databse after db.SubmitChanges() wright ? Linq query should work fine but Submit doesn't see the change becouse there is no change in table2. You only select data and group it from table1. Please debug and see what is in q variable.

Comment: do you think i can do something like binding the first table to a gridview and the sum the column i want in that using "for()" and then transfer that sum to the other table?